# Android TextureView canvas drawing problems

Tags: android, 2d, surfaceview

I have an app that used SurfaceView to draw dynamic 2D graphs. It worked ok but transformations etc as we know are not supported. So I went to TextureView. My old code used another class/thread to do the drawing via the Surfaceholder.lockCanvas(); So I changed this to TextureView.lockcanvas. When this runs the canvas not accelerated (the view is) does not display initially but if I touch the screen onSurfaceTextureUpdated (currently with no code inside) is called and it displays???

```
protected void RenderCanvas(){
//mCanvas = null;
Canvas c = null;
//synchronized (mCanvas) {
    //mCanvas = null;
    try {
        c = mChartView.lockCanvas(null);
         if (!c.isHardwareAccelerated()) {
               Log.w("GVIEW", "A TextureView or a subclass can only be "
                         + "used with hardware acceleration enabled.");
           }
        synchronized (mCanvas) {
            c.drawBitmap(buffBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        }
    } finally {
        // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
        // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
        // inconsistent state
        if (c != null) {
            mChartView.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            //mSurfaceHolder.updateTexImage();
        }
    }
```

}

I implement the SurfaceTextureListener within my TextureView and all of the program flow seems fine a real surface is handed to the plotting thread by

```
@Override

public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width,

        int height) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    isRunning = true;

    mySurface = surface;

    mChart.setTextureSurface(surface);

    mChart.setSurfaceSize(width, height);

    mChart.Redraw(true) 

}
```

This void finishes with the RenderCanvas() above.

Redrawing or invalidating the view also doesn't work unless i again touch the screen.

Cannot I not use TextureView like this?

Does it have to be openGl content stream?

Comment: It is important to note that only one producer can use the TextureView.
 * For instance, if you use a TextureView to display the camera preview, you
 * cannot use {@link #lockCanvas()} to draw onto the TextureView at the same
 * time. --> android doc